# mvc pagedlist page number not incrementing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I'm using MVC 5 along with PagedList.MVC 4.5.0.0, I have data coming back and displaying on my table, along with the pager controls showing up.  when I click next though, the pager continues to send page = 1 to my function, see that while debugging.

my page has:

```
                <div class="pagedList" data-otf-target="#contractList">
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
            </div>
```

my method which sends the data back to the action is

```
        public IPagedList<ContractViewModel> GetAllContracts(int page = 1)
    {
        var lstcontractViewModel = new List<ContractViewModel>();
        using (ContractRepository contractRepos = new ContractRepository(new UnitOfWork()))
        {
            var activeContractList = contractRepos.All.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id);

            foreach (var activeContract in activeContractList)
            {
                Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClasses.ActiveContract, ActiveContractViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.ContractorModel, opts => opts.Ignore());

                Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
                lstcontractViewModel.Add(Mapper.Map<ActiveContractViewModel>(activeContract));
            }
        }

        return lstcontractViewModel.ToPagedList(page, 40);
    }
```

and my controller's action is

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var contracts = activeaccountController.GetAllContracts(); 
        return View(contracts);
    }
```

as I said everything comes up fine for the 1st page, just when the GetAllContracts method is called, the debugger shows page is always = 1. so paging is always returning just the 1st page of results.  i have over 2500 records, so other data is there, as the pager also shows that, pager says "Showing items 1 through 40 of 2546."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
```

try to set new{page = somevalue} and it will send in a param.

```
Public ActionResult Index(int page) 

public IPagedList<ContractViewModel> GetAllContracts(int page = 1)
```

This means that page is default 1 if no other param is applied.

```
var contracts = activeaccountController.GetAllContracts(page);
```

For more info read https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList